# Marker going outside the roads- even after using Google Map SnapToRoadAPI and Direction API

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-polyline, google-directions-api

I am trying to show the path of my vehicle for a past trip and want to replay the vehicle moving on that path.

I used my array of coordinates and used the SnapToRoad API to get all coordinates which are on the Roads. After getting all the points, I have used the Direction API to get the polylines on the road and plotted that on the map.

I have plotted the polyline on road successfully. Now I'm trying to show a marker along the path. So I have created a list by decrypting the polyline. But when I mark the marker on the map at some places the coordinates are going out of the road.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated